# InteliJ does not recognize one of two docker compose file as compose file

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose

I've had this problem for about a year and a half, but i haven't done anything about it up until now.
My work colleague doesn't have this problem on his PC, when he looks at his compose files.
So it seems that i have done something at some point to have my IDEA behave this way.

[image: Folder structure]

This is how my folder structure looks. Notice how on the develop compose file icon there is no "C" to signify that it is a "Compose" file.

[image: develop compose file]

This is how the inside of my develop compose file looks.

[image: master compose file]

And this is how the the inside of my master compose file looks like.

I await your guidance fellow humans.

EDIT:

Here is the requested screenshot of my file type settings.
[image: filetypesettings]

Comment: Please share the screenshot [showing the file types](https://i.imgur.com/8kdYQTq.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `docker-compose-develop.yml` from the `Dockerfile` file type.

Yaml docker-compose files are not related to Dockerfile and will have `DC` icon when IDE detects `version` and `services` in the file.